# Ubuntu studio desktop doesn't render properly

Tags: boot, video, xfce, 20.04, ubuntu-studio

I have just installed Ubuntu studio 20.04 and the desktop renders like this:

[image: Ubuntu studio desktop]

All the other screens like the loading screen and login screen look normal. Only after logging in, the desktop looks like this. What could be the problem? I can provide any additional information needed and help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are you using AMD/ATI graphics card?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem a while ago, you just gotta set the resolution lower for a bit, so it will render alright, then go to "Settings > window manager tweaks > compositor" and disable it, you'll have less cool effects in your system but it will work with your native resolution. I hope this helped you!