# Display crash or bug

Tags: display, crash, ubuntu-studio

barely installed Ubuntu Studio 20.04. And my display looks like it doesn't arranged correctly. All keyboards function are normal and the os function is normal. It is just this display thing, how to *fix* this please.
The display is divided into segments horizontally, and should be arranged vertically. But it doesn't, it's somehow arranged diagonally and stacked. [how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpiRE.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238082/ubuntu-studio-desktop-doesnt-render-properly

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Settings > window manager tweaks > compositor" and disable it, you'll have less cool effects in your system but it will work with your native resolution.

Comment: Oh yea and by the way, you have to lower your resolution first to be able to see something in your screen lol.